# How can I find a result by its row number?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Say I have two models, Foo belongsTo Bar:

```
$this->Foo->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'barRowNumber'=>$barRowNumber,
        'fooRowNumber'=>$fooRowNumber)));
```

I can't just do the auto_increment id because they skip around when I add and delete records. So how can I use row number as a parameter for a find query in CakePHP?

Comment: Use a real example, not Foo and Bar. It's hard to tell why you'd want to do what you're doing, and if you're going the right way about it. Why do you need to fetch a record based on the value of a belongsTo row number? PS - you should follow cakePHP conventions to name your database fields, eg bar_row_number

Answer (score 0):

1. If you dont have id then you should count the row where your search occur.
2. If you have ID then `$this->Foo->id = $value` is the key
3. If you have other search value then `$this->Foo->findbyYourValue` will do